# Module '"react-router-dom"' has no exported member 'RouteComponentProps'? this happens in version 6

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm facing problem with this. I am facing problem particularly at these 3 lines

1. `import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';`
2. `const RestaurantDetails = ({ match }: RouteComponentProps<{ id: string }>) => {`
3. `const data = await getRestaurantById(+match.params.id);`

Code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faClock } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { Col, Row, Badge } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Alert from 'react-bootstrap/Alert';
import { NullLiteral } from 'typescript';
import IRestaurant from '../../models/IRestaurants';
import { LoadingStatus } from '../../models/types';
import LoadingIndicator from '../common/LoadingIndicator';
import Rating from '../common/Rating';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';

import { getRestaurantById } from '../../services/restaurants';
import Menu from '../menu/Menu';

const RestaurantDetails = ({ match }: RouteComponentProps<{ id: string }>) => {

   const [status, setStatus] = useState<LoadingStatus>("LOADING");
   const [restaurant, setRestaurant] = useState<IRestaurant | null>(null);
   const [error, setError] = useState<Error | null>(null);

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchRestaurant = async () => {
        try {
            const data = await getRestaurantById(+match.params.id);
            setRestaurant(data);
            setStatus("LOADED")
        } catch (error: any) {
            setError(error);
            setStatus("ERROR_LOADING");
        }
    };
    fetchRestaurant();
},
    []);
```

Comment: In this question, once an answer was given, the question was then substantially modified with new code. This would render the answer useless, since it could not have been given if the question was in the newer state. I have therefore rolled it back, so that future readers can see that the answer is a natural response to the question.

Comment: If you have more questions, please ask a new question. If you want to show the working code, please supply an additional answer - self answers are welcome here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no route props in `react-router@6`. Use the provided React hooks to access the params you need.

Example:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const RestaurantDetails = () => {
  const { id } = useParams() as { id: string };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchRestaurant = async () => {
      try {
        const data = await getRestaurantById(id);
        setRestaurant(data);
        setStatus("LOADED");
      } catch (error: any) {
        setError(error);
        setStatus("ERROR_LOADING");
      }
    };

    fetchRestaurant();
  }, [id]);

  ...
```

[image: Edit module-react-router-dom-has-no-exported-member-routecomponentprops-this-h]

Comment: Still it's not working. I'm sharing my whole code, once look at it

Comment: @SaiSrikanth Sorry, mixed up some typing, try `const { id } = useParams() as { id: string };` instead. If you've still an issue from here can you update your post to include a more complete [mcve] and more details on what isn't working?

Comment: @SaiSrikanth Ah, great. I just finished getting a small codesandbox demo running. I'll include it anyway. Cheers and good luck!

Comment: CodeSandbox is working very nice. We Don't need to shift browser and app, both are there, we can instantly see the result side.